# How to Fix NaN Error - Argument Values Not Adding, Subtracting, Dividing, or Multiplying - In JavaScript

Tags: javascript, math, arguments

I'm ultimately trying to solve [this kata](https://www.codewars.com/kata/holiday-vi-shark-pontoon/train/javascript) on CodeWars.

To start with, I'm just trying to get the "rate" of the person's speed.

```
function shark(pontoonDistance, sharkDistance, youSpeed, sharkSpeed, dolphin) {

let yourRate = pontoonDistance / youSpeed;

return yourRate;

}
console.log(shark((12, 50, 4, 8, true)));
```

But this is returning `NaN`. That doesn't make any sense. This similar code will return `2`:

```
function divide(firstValue, secondValue) {
    let newValue = secondValue / firstValue;
    return newValue; 
}

console.log(divide(3, 6));
```

What's  different about these situation, that would cause the first to return `NaN`?

I plan to compare vs another variable, `sharkRate` `(sharkDistance / sharkSpeed)`. If yourRate is greater than sharkRate, the person will swim to safety.

But to start with, I'm just trying to figure out why `yourRate` is returning `NaN`?

Thank you.

Comment: How are you calling `shark` and with what arguments? Which arguments return `NaN`?

Comment: @JackBashford sorry I've added the `console.log` that I was using.

Comment: After looking at my own code, I noticed that the console.log has too many parentheses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue in your current code is you have an extra pair of parentheses inside your `shark` call. This was causing your code to attempt to divide `(12, 50, 4, 8, true)` by `undefined` (because this was the only argument passed, and the `youSpeed` didn't exist. Removing these will fix your problem:

```js
function shark(pontoonDistance, sharkDistance, youSpeed, sharkSpeed, dolphin) {

let yourRate = pontoonDistance / youSpeed;

return yourRate;

}
console.log(shark(12, 50, 4, 8, true));
```

Answer (score 1):

I had too many parentheses in my `console.log`.

I changed `console.log(shark((12, 50, 4, 8, true)));`

to `console.log(shark(12, 50, 4, 8, true));`